# Unable to start docker on minikube

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I get the error below when I run `minikube start --driver=docker`. I checked the status of my docker service and it was active.

```
  Exiting due to PROVIDER_DOCKER_NOT_RUNNING: "docker version --format <no value>-<no value>:<no value>" exit status 1: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///home/user/.docker/desktop/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
  Suggestion: Start the Docker service
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `credsStore` and `currentContext` properties from `$HOME/.docker/config.json`. The context is set to docker desktop, so if you are no longer using docker desktop then you should remove these two properties and run `minikube start --driver=docker` (make sure to delete the trailing comma).

Else if you are using docker desktop just launch it from your application programs and run `minikube start --driver=docker`